# Operator on $\ell^2$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I have an operator $A \in B(\ell^2)$, $Ax=(0,x_1,\frac{1}{2}x_2, \frac{1}{3}x_3,...),\; x=(x_1, x_2, x_3,...) \in \ell^2$. 
I need to find the following and I am not sure even how to start:

- proof that it is compact
- show that zero is in spectrum
- find the spectrum

Thanks a lot

Comment: This is the operator norm limit of some finite rank operators, whence compact. The nonzero spectral values of a compact operator on a Banach space must be eigenvalues with finite multiplicities. What happens if you look for eigenvalues and eigenvectors?

Answer (score 2):

1. It's an isometry (the shift) post-composed with a compact operator, therefore compact.
2. Neither the shift nor the compact operator is invertible, therefore your operator is not invertible, i.e. $0$ is in the spectrum.
3. The spectrum of the shift is the closed unit disk. Try to mimic that calculation for your operator.